# Problems trying to add logo's within golem shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, golem

I have an issue with adding logo's with the golem arhitecture. This is a bit more complex than I thought.

I am trying to refactor a code for an app deploying golem. so the original code (I won't add the full code since it is huge) looks like this:

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    windowTitle = "Page",
    title = div(img(src = "bare.png", height = "30px"), "Oncology  Toolbox"),
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    tabPanel(
      "Toolbox", icon = icon("wrench"),
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Tools", titleWidth = 300),
        dashboardSidebar(
          width = 300,
          tags$head(HTML(
           
          )),
          br(),
          br(),
          sidebarMenu(
            id = "",
            menuItem("Pathways",
                     tabName = "geneapp", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                     selected = TRUE),
            menuItem("Genomic", tabName = "mutapp",
                     icon = icon("universal-access")),
        dashboardBody(
          tabItems(
            ## Group 1: Pathways
            tabItem(
              tabName = "geneapp",
              fluidRow(
                headerPanel(h3("Analysis")),
                br(),
                column(
                  3,
                  thumbnail_label(
                    url = "RStudio_FLAT/",
                    image = "FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png",
                    tool = "Fludigm_Browser",
                    label = "Fludigm Browser",
                    content = "Perform Fluidigm data analysis"
                  )
                ),
                column(
                  3,
                  thumbnail_label(
                    url = "home",
                    image = "gtex.png",
                    tool = "GTEx",
                    label = "GTEx Portal",
                    content = "Gene expression in normal tissue"
                  )
                ),
                br(),
                
           etc.... etc...
```

Yet, with golem my code ui, which I want to keep this way, looks like this:

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    # Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    # Your application UI logic
    shinyUI(
      navbarPage(
        windowTitle = "Page",
        title = div(img(src = ".png", height = "30px"), " Toolbox"),
        theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("cerulean"),
        tabPanel("Toolbox", icon = icon("wrench"),
                 shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
                   header = shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "   ", titleWidth = 300),
                   shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
                     width = 300 ,
                     shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
                       shinydashboard::menuItem(
                         "Tools",
                         tabName = "tools_app",
                         icon = icon("wrench"),
                         shinydashboard::menuSubItem(
                           "Pathways",
                           tabName = "gene_app",
                           icon = icon("chart-line")
                         ),
                         shinydashboard::menuSubItem(
                           "Genomic",
                           tabName = "genomic_app",
                           icon = icon("universal-access")
                         )),
                       shinydashboard::tabItem("gene_app",mod_gene_expressions_sign_path_ui("gene_expression_sign_path_ui_1")),
                       shinydashboard::tabItem("genomic_app", mod_genomic_ui("genomic_ui_1")),

        tabPanel(
          "Tutorials", icon = icon("graduation-cap")),
        tabPanel("Worflows", icon = icon("list"))
      )))
}
```

The only code/module you should look into is

shinydashboard::tabItem("gene_app",mod_gene_expressions_sign_path_ui("gene_expression_sign_path_ui_1"))

However, as you can see, there is a thumbnail_label function that is added within code above, that takes the logo into. This is the function:

```
label <- function(url, image, label="", content="", tool="misc",
                            category = "tool") {
  tags$a(
    href = url,
    onclick = paste0("gtag('event', 'click', { 'event_category': '", category,
                     "', 'event_label': '", tool, "'});"),
    target = "_blank",
    div(class = "row",
      div(class = "col-sm-14 col-md-12",
        div(class = "thumbnail",
          img(src = image, alt = "...",
            div(class = "caption", h3(label), p(content))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Now, thumbnail_label function with golem infrastructure is added within 02_dev file, within dev folder.

All logos that I need in the above code, are all in www folder within the simple dashboard app infrastructure. I want to keep all the logos within this folder ins/app/www

Yet do not know how to add the logo's within thumbnail_label but with golem shiny app infrastructure.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you have defined the thumbnail function twice, and the second one is incorrect.

---

Have a look into the HTML code of your app:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see, the `<img>` HTML tag is not correctly created.

Which you can see by running the following code:

```r
> pkgload::load_all()
ℹ Loading bftb
> thumbnail_label(
+             url = "https:///RStudio_FLAT/",
+             image = "www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png",
+             tool = "Fludigm_Browser",
+             label = "Fludigm Browser",
+             content = "Perform Fluidigm data analysis"
+           )
<a href="https:RStudio_FLAT/" onclick="gtag(&#39;event&#39;, &#39;click&#39;, { &#39;event_category&#39;: &#39;tool&#39;, &#39;event_label&#39;: &#39;Fludigm_Browser&#39;});" target="_blank">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-14 col-md-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="www" alt="...">
          www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Fludigm Browser</h3>
            <p>Perform Fluidigm data analysis</p>
          </div>
        </img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Issue is:

```html
        <img src="www" alt="...">
          www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png
```

This function is correctly defined in https://github.com/fct_thumbnail_label.R

but you have defined it a second time in https://github.com/gabrielburcea/bftb/blob/gene_expr_sign_path/R/thumbnail_label.R and this second one is wrong.

So if you remove this second file, you'll get what you want.

```r
> unlink("R/thumbnail_label.R")
> pkgload::load_all()
ℹ Loading bftb
> thumbnail_label(
+             url = "https:///RStudio_FLAT/",
+             image = "www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png",
+             tool = "Fludigm_Browser",
+             label = "Fludigm Browser",
+             content = "Perform Fluidigm data analysis"
+           )
<a href="https://RStudio_FLAT/" onclick="gtag(&#39;event&#39;, &#39;click&#39;, { &#39;event_category&#39;: &#39;tool&#39;, &#39;event_label&#39;: &#39;Fludigm_Browser&#39;});" target="_blank">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-14 col-md-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="www/FluidigmAnalysisToolkit.v2.png" alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Fludigm Browser</h3>
            <p>Perform Fluidigm data analysis</p>
          </div>
        </img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked by deleting the function you've mentioned. Thanks for writing this package!

Comment: Super, happy to hear that :)

Comment: is there a possibility to add html but in modules rather than app_ui ?